# How can I perform GET method in android?

Tags: android, get

I want to get this data ---->"**#1$Egypt$مصر@**" 
from this link --> "**http://184.173.7.132/mobile.aspx?action=4**"

I used this code but the response is `NULL`

```
    public HttpResponse doGet(String url) throws Exception {

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

}
```

Comment: do you get the IOException maybe? - Have you added INTERNET permissions to the manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code it is worked for your url. add internet permission in manifest

```
String page;


DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://184.173.7.132/mobile.aspx?action=4");

                 // httpGet.addHeader("Content-type","application/json");


                  ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                try
                {
                    page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
                } 
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
                  Log.e("response",page);
```

Comment: what is this line "Log.e("response",page);" do??

Comment: just to see response in logcat, you can use Toast instead

Comment: I have another problem in parsing the resulted string.... the array 'splitc' in this line of code "String[] splitC=page.split("$"));" is still have the value #1$Egypt$مصر@ after parsing .. what goes wrong with it :S